# What is the comparator circuit?

Tags: complexity-theory, sorting, complexity-classes, circuits, matching

The standard circuits $AC^i$, $NC^i$ are constructed using $AND$, $OR$ and $NOT$ of various fan-ins, fan-outs and depths.

What is the comparator gate constituted from?

Structurally why is it believed $NC^i$ is not in any $CC^j$ if $i\geq 1$ and why is it believed $CC^i$ is not in any $NC^j$ if $i\geq 1$ (refer https://arxiv.org/abs/1208.2721 for the conjecture $NC$ and $CC$ are incomparable)?

Comment: Comparator circuits are described in the paper. You don't need us to help you read the paper.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A comparator circuit is a circuit computing a function on $x_1,\ldots,x_n \in \{0,1\}^n$. The inputs to the circuit are labeled with either constants ($0$ or $1$), inputs ($x_1,\ldots,x_n$) or negated inputs ($\lnot x_1,\ldots,\lnot x_n$). The only allowed gate is a comparator gate, which has two inputs $a,b$ and two outputs $a\land b,a\lor b$. The circuit has no *fan-out*, that is, an output cannot be duplicated. One of the "wires" is designated as an output (just like a usual circuit).

Equivalently, we can represent a comparator circuit as a "straight-line program" with $m$ variables $z_1,\ldots,z_m$, each initialized by a constant, an input, or a negated input. The program itself is a sequence of instructions of the form $$ z_i,z_j \gets z_i \land z_j,z_i \lor z_j. $$ One of the variables $z_o$ is the output of the circuit.

It is believed that CC and NC are incomparable since nobody managed to show that one of them is contained in the other. Usually, such inclusions are either easy or false, though sometimes this intuition is wrong (the best example is SL=L).

Comment: The straightline representation is interesting but so can any Boolean *formula* be given as a straightline having negated inputs and OR and AND gates and we can reuse variables and if we desire to keep number of variables in every layer similar we can update the unused variables in a dummy manner.

Comment: The difference is that in usual circuits, we allow instructions which don’t erase the inputs.

Comment: It appears $CC$ seems to be having identical straightline representation to any boolean circuit where number of instructions which do not erase the inputs is $0$. We can introduce dummy instructions $z\leftarrow z$ or $z\leftarrow{garbage}$ if we are not using the input variables $z$ again in the straightline representation of the boolean *formula*.

Comment: You can implement CC using a usual circuit, but not the other way around.

Comment: Say you have a formula of $AND$ and $OR$ having negated inputs and no $NOT$ gates. Say fan-out is $1$ and fan-in is $2$. For every $AND$ gate can't we introduce a dummy $OR$ gate and for every $OR$ gate can't we introduce dummy $AND$ gate? Technically the wires which are not being used again can be used to route dummy information (the desired output position changes) but it appears we can embed $NC$ formula in $CC$ circuits of similar depth and for every $NC$-formula we compute the correct output wire and utilizing polynomially many additional wires route the correct output wire to the top.

Comment: If the fan-out is 1 then you have a formula. They can be simulated in CC. It is conjectured that formulas are less powerful than circuits (in terms of complexity).

Comment: I see $NC^2$ is in quasi-poly $NC^2$-formula but not known to be in $NC^2$ formula. Makes sense. So is $NL$ in $CC^1$ (I really am unable to infer in the paper)? On basis of the comment it appears since perfect matching is not in $NL$. It appears perfect matching might be in $CC^2$ but uncertain.

Comment: All current knowledge is summarized in the paper. If it’s not there, it’s not known.

Comment: Honestly on page $33$ it talks of a machine model corresponding to a characterization in theorem $12$. But it appears at best murky and totally unclear what the depth should be? At every place $CC$ is utilized the terminology $CC^i$ is avoided and I am not sure if it is intentional because of uncertainty in depth or it is avoided for a reason and figure $14$ clearly indicates $\omega(n)$ depth (since it illustrates an example of reachability on $5$ vertices by repeating a gadget $5$ times).

Comment: "..$\Omega(n)$ depth".

Comment: Perhaps the authors simply didn’t care about the depth in the case of comparator circuits.

Comment: Ok I am surprised NC is not in CC if we are considering comparator circuits to be of arbitrary depth while NC by definition is of polylog depth.

Comment: Consider a layered $SAC^i$ where unbounded fanin $OR$ alternates bounded fanin $AND$. $OR$ can be replaced by $CC^1$ circuits while $AND$ by $CC^0$. It appears $SAC^i$ should be in $CC^{i+1}$ but maybe there is a reason the substitution cannot be performed.

Comment: CC circuits have no fan-out.